# Confusion between CLT and asymptotic normality

Tags: probability-theory

I am a bit confused with respect to asymptotic normality, and how to prove it.

The examples I have seen just kind of state that "oh, it's obvious from CLT", but what is the exact, formal derivation?

Let' take a simple multidimensional example: Given a sequence $(X_k)_k$ of iid variables, we consider $$\begin{pmatrix} 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k  \\ 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

All relevant variances and moments exist. Now, what is the exact derivation of why this is asymptotically normal with mean $\xi$ and variance $1/n \Sigma$?

Comment: I don't know if I get your question right, but if you want some formal proof, you can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT .
Then, ask me again if you have some questions, specifically on what part.

Answer (score 0):

One may write $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k  \\ 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}  X_k  \\ X_k^2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Let $Y_k = \begin{pmatrix}  X_k  \\ X_k^2 \end{pmatrix}$. Since the $X_k$ are independent, for any measurable $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$, the $f(X_k)$ are independent (and identically distributed).

Consider $f:x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}  x  \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}$ and you'll get that the $Y_k$ are iid.

Now you may apply the $2$ dimensional version of the CLT to the $Y_k$.